# PHP - Print all the combinations - product

Tags: php

I'm trying to solve a somewhat simple task but can't wrap my head around doing it without a lot of loops and messy code.

I want all to print all combinations of the array below:

```
$product = array(
    array
    (
        '1X'
    ),
    array
    (
        'X2'
    )
);
```

producing the following result:

> //ROW 1
>   1
>   X
>
> //ROW 2
>   X
>   2
>
> //ROW 3
>   1
>   2
>
> //ROW 4
>   X
>   X

Comment: `$product` only have two arrays inner?

Comment: No it can have as many as it wants and the combinations can vary between 1,X,2 or only two or all three of them.

Comment: This is called Cartesian product for arrays in PHP, you are making Cartesian of array strings, [here](https://gist.github.com/jwage/11193216) use this library.

Comment: @Viral oh thank you mate, that explained alot cheers

Answer (score 1):

this work:

```
$product = array(
    array
    (
        '1WQ'
    ),
    array
    (
        '3'
    ),
    array
    (
        'X'
    )
);
//
class Combine{
    private $product = array();
    private $result = array();
    private $format = array();
    public function __construct($p=array()){
        $this->product = $p;
    }
    public function process(){
        foreach($this->product as $k=>$v){
            $this->format[] = str_split($v[0]);
        }
        $this->result = $this->build();
        return $this;
    }
    public function build()
    { 
        if (!$this->format) {
            return array(array());
        }
        $sub = array_shift($this->format);
        $c = $this->build($this->format);
        $res = array();
        foreach ($sub as $v) {
            foreach ($c as $p) {
                array_unshift($p, $v);
                $res[] = $p;
            }
        }
        return $res;        
    }
    public function response(){
        return $this->result;
    }
}
//
$combine = new Combine($product);
$resp = $combine->process()->response();
var_dump($resp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function helperFunction($array, $index, $workArray)
{
    $tempArray = array();
    $tmpStr    = $array[$index][0];

    // loop over the current array characters
    for( $i = 0; $i < strlen($tmpStr); $i++ )
    {
        $char = substr($tmpStr, $i, 1);

        // first time - add characters to the work array
        if (count($workArray) == 0)
        {
            $tempArray[] = $char;
        }
        // later round - add characters to existing items
        else
        {
            foreach ($workArray as $workItem)
            {
                $tempArray[] = $workItem . $char;
            }
        }
    }

    // last round
    if (count($array) == $index + 1)
    {
        return $tempArray;
    }
    // recursion round
    else
    {
        return helperFunction($array, $index + 1, $tempArray);
    }
}

$result = helperFunction($product, 0, array());
```